# Is it possible to have a bar chart with bars centered on the 0 value of the y axis

Tags: javascript, charts, dc.js

Using the built-in chart types of dc.js, is it possible to render a bar chart where the bars are centered on the zero value of the y axis?

I would like to get a chart that looks like this:

[image: Bar chart with bars centered on 0-y axis]

I tried using a box plot, but it seems that the effort required to coerce my data to render the correct bar heights and get rid of the percentile and error bar indicators will be greater that simply creating a custom chart type for dc.js.

Comment: So, the size of the bars is always mirrored in Y, i.e. the negative value is equal to the positive value times -1? There's nothing built-in to do this but I think you may be able to do it with a [renderlet/pretransition handler](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#basemixinonevent-listener--basemixin).

Comment: I was able to get the correct mirrored shape through a renderlet as you recommended. Thank you.
Unfortunately this combined with the transitions is not very sightly. I might have to create a custom chart type after all.

Comment: I think it may be a matter of using the pretransition handler along with a transition to the location/size that you want. Renderlet is the old way and it applies after the transitions, which creates an ugly jump as you say. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30673705/676195) has an example of applying a transition within the pretransition handler. Tricky but I think it works seamlessly.